# Add a span tag to Title without javascript

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

**UPDATE:
Yes I am Using PHP in my pages.**

Hello Friends I was thinking..... Is there a way to add a `<span>` tag to the title without using javascript?

May be using Regex or php or some other method. I dont really know.

Let me explain....

My HTML is like this:

```
<h3 class="title">The Title Goes Here</h3>
```

What I want is to automatically add a span tag, so the the final HTML looks like this.

```
<h3 class="title"><span>The </span>Title Goes Here</h3>
```

I want to wrap **only the first word** of the title in a `<span>` tag.

I know this can easily be dont using Javascript but I am looking for a non-javascript solution.

Please Help!

Comment: You don't give any indication of context. Is the HTML page being generated by PHP, served off disk via a web server, or indeed just loaded from a file on the same computer as the web browser?

Comment: Is your HTML generated by PHP? Then it should be fairly easy to adjust this process. If it is a static file then just edit it.

Comment: @James Aylett Yes I am using PHP in my pages.

Comment: @Felix Kling Yes I am using PHP in my pages.

Comment: You should provide some more information then. How is `<h3 class="title">The Title Goes Here</h3>` generated?

Comment: @Felix Kling I am actually building a theme for my WordPress based site. I do not want to use any Javascript in the frontend. I want to keep this very-very light-weight. These Heading will be the Widget Titles and also the Menu has a Topline and a sub-line so this span tag will actually be used to add diferrent formatting the Menu's top-line, sub-line and the Widget titles. To make this happen I need to wrap the FIRST WORD of the title in a span tag. Rest my CSS will handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) in PHP if you don't want to do it with the javascript DOM:

```
$html = '<h3 class="title">The Title Goes Here</h3>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($xp->query('//h3[@class="title"]') as $parent) {
    $title = $parent->nodeValue;
    list($first, $rest) = explode(' ', $title, 2);
    $span = new DOMElement('span', $first. ' ');
    $parent->nodeValue = $rest;
    $parent->insertBefore($span, $parent->firstChild);
}
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $node)
{
    echo $doc->saveHTML($node);
}
```

Comment: Hi @hakre Thanks for helping. Could you please explain a bit more in detail as to ho do I do this for multiple titles? Yes I am using php in my pages.

Comment: The code example does work on every `<h3>` tag with the `class="title"`. For 0, one or more.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is that the cannot be done.  You can't manipulate a page in the browser without JavaScript. This can only be achieved by editing the page on the server manually, or by dynamically generating it using PHP logic, or an equivalent solution, of which there are many.

If you are doing this for a corporate solution that is only used on a single corporate standard browser, you could look into building a plugin for the browser.